# Текст бегающий за мышью

Tags: javascript

Знаю, что в инете полно примеров такой задачи, но я вот не могу понять, что надо изменить именно в этом коде, чтобы за мышью бегал текст а не картинка [КЛАЦ](http://pastebin.com/EchiMLzv)

Пробовал с параграфом и потом в js ссылался на него вместо (pImage), но не вышло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-идее, создать div с именем pimage.

```
<div id="IMG" name="pimage">...
```

и для дива проставить стиль

```
div#IMG

   { position : absolute; }
```

Но там трэш начала 2000, так что рекомендую поискать более удачный пример

UPD:

http://jsfiddle.net/HHuav/

Comment: @knes, Так тоже не выходит. Я бы с радостью, но это задание.

Comment: Обновил.
То, что я запихнул функцию движения внутрь setInterval - это из-за того, что мне лень было возиться с jsFiddleовской оберткой. Это необязательно

Comment: @knes, ты точно ту ссыль кинул?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HHuav/ точно не ту. =))

Answer (score 1):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<TITLE>Картинка-указатель</TITLE>
<STYLE>
SPAN
{
    float : left;
    position : absolute;
}
BODY
{
    background: 9999FF;
    color: 000099;
}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var x, y, ix, iy, timID, pImage;

function setupAnim()
{
    pImage = document.getElementById('pImage');
    timID = window.setInterval('imgMove()',10);
}

function imgMove()
{
    var l = 10;

    if (x >= ix)
        if (x - ix > l) ix += l;
        else ix = x;
    else
        if (ix - x > l) ix -= l;
        else ix = x;
    if (y >= iy)
        if (y - iy > l) iy += l;
        else iy = y;
    else
        if (iy - y > l) iy -= l;
        else iy = y;

    pImage.style.left = x;
    pImage.style.top = y;
}

function Move()
{
    x = window.event.clientX;
    y = window.event.clientY;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad = "setupAnim()" onmousemove = "Move()">
    <SPAN id="pImage" STYLE = "left:0; top:0; width:36">TEXT</SPAN>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```